# using Jensen-Shannon Divergence for more than two data sets as a distance metric

Tags: distributions, distance

I know that Jensen-Shannon Divergence for two distribution is symmetric. Is it possible to use JSD as a distance? In other words, is there a version of JSD that satisfies all the requirements for distance: non-negative, symmetric and triangle inequality? I want to use JSD for comparing distances between more than a pair of distributions together. My understanding is that the triangle inequality needs to be satisfied (on top of symmetric and non-negative requirements) to be able to compare JSD distance between a pair of distribution with another pair of distribution.  Is this understanding correct? if so what's the appropriate notation? The version for more than two distributions from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence) doesn't seem to satisfy the requirements for symmetric and triangular inequality.

To clarify, let's say I calculate JSD between two distributions A and B as: JSD(A, B)= x and JSD(B,C)=y now if x>y can I say B is closer to C than A? or in another scenario: JSD(A, B)= x and JSD(B,C)=y, JSD(D,E) = Z, and y>z, can I say D and E are more similar to each other than B and C?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "distance ... between more than two distributions"? By definition, a distance is a function of a *pair* of objects.

Comment: @whuber what I mean is that let's say  I calculate JSD between two distributions A and B  as: JSD(A, B)= x and JSD(B,C)=y now if x>y can I say B is closer to C than A? or in another scenario: JSD(A, B)= x and JSD(B,C)=y, JSD(D,E) = Z, and y>z, can I say D and E are more similar to each other than B and C?

Comment: That kind of language is perfectly acceptable with metrics (distance functions).  You can take the mathematical statements as *definitions* of what "closer to" and "more similar" mean.

Comment: @whuber but is JS a distance function? My understanding is that it's just divergence and doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality requirement.

Comment: I see.  Why don't you edit your post to emphasize you are asking whether the JSD satisfies the triangle inequality?  On the other hand, since you have already noted it is not symmetric, then manifestly it's not a metric!

Comment: I thought I did. But I will reword and re-emphasize. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @whuber edited my question hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: It still is not evident what you mean by "using" a distance "between more than two distributions."  Could you state what kind of property such a thing would be?

Comment: @whuber I have clarified that " Is there a version of JSD that satisfies all the requirements for distance: non-negative, symmetric and triangle inequality so that it can be used between more than two distributions?"  is this not clear? what is missing?

Comment: The mystifying part is the clause "so that it can be used between more than two distributions."  It remains unclear what you might mean by that.

Comment: it can be used between more than two distributions if it satisfies all three requirements for distance: non-negative, symmetric and triangle inequality .

Comment: I added some more context, maybe that makes it clear. Maybe, my understanding is so wrong that the question fails to make sense lol

Comment: Let's consider what that might mean in a completely analogous context.  Consider the Euclidean plane.  Could you explain what the "distance" between three points would be?  Would it mean the maximum of the distances? An average?  The median?  Something else?

Comment: @whuber in the context of Euclidean, if A and B have a distance of 2, and C and D have a distance of 4, we can conclude that A and B are closer to each other than C and D are to each other. But here we already satisfy all the requirements of a "distance". This distance is non-negative, it's symmetric and triangle inequality, therefore, the distance between pair A and B is comparable with pair C and D.

Comment: My question is, can the same conclusion be made when we are not using a distance and we are using a divergence function instead. In the case of JSD divergence, it doesn't seem to satisfy the triangle inequality and even symmetry. Can we still compare the divergence of A and B with C and D?